# Propane v. Natural Gas

Tags: equipment, boil, propane-burner

I just moved to a home where there is natural gas being piped into the garage for a garage heater.  I was thinking of re-tooling my burners with jet/orifices that can handle the lower pressure of the natural gas v. the propane tank hook ups I use now.

Does natural gas have more or less BTUs than the propane?
Would you expect a longer or shorter "time to boil" if I switch over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading [these figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Heat_of_combustion_tables) correctly, Natural Gas contains 23,000 BTUs/Lb. vs Propane's 21,000 BTUs/Lb.  How the propane council baka references comes up with their numbers likely has more to do with marketing spin (measuring energy density by volume, not mass) than science, I suspect.  How effectively you can utilize that and what it's going to cost you is another thing entirely, but as far as I can tell, Natural Gas is more energy dense by weight than Propane.

Comment: Natural gas is pretty darn cheap, from what I've read about 5 times cheaper than propane.  It's also supposed to be a little safer.  Since it is lighter than air it can't pool up and ignite like propane can.

Comment: ha, nice.   i didn't catch their method of measurement, but a few other sites i looked at quoted similar numbers.   of course, that's why i pointed out that they have an interest in selling propane.

Comment: @Room3 not to mention most folks have the option of piping natural gas in.  Propane generally requires either swapping out 20# tanks at the gas station of having someone fill a large on-site tank.

Comment: When you convert a propane burner to natural gas you will loose some heating power.  Propane regulators dispense gas from 10-40 psi where your natural gas coming from your home meter is usually at 1 psi sometimes 2 psi in newer developments.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because its good and the comments really help too.

Answer (score 0):

[Brought to you by the propane council](http://www.propane101.com/propanevsnaturalgas.htm)

It looks like propane is more than twice as energy dense as natural gas.

I do not know if that means a 100kBTU burner would be a less-than 50kBTU burner when using the different fuel, though.